# Checking SSIS variable of Object data type for NULL Value

Tags: ssis

everyone,
In my SSIS package, I have a variable FilesInfo of Object data type that gets its values from the Full Result Set from  an Execute SQL task, which may or may not return any results. I have a Foreach loop container to do further processing.  If the values are not null, the package executes successfully. However, it throws an error when nothing returned fromthe SQL task.
To fix this, I want to add a Precedence Constraint to direct the flow only when FilesInfo is NOT NULL. Is there a way to do it? And if so, what is the exact syntax?
Thank you for your help in advance.
Regards

Comment: Exclude them in your SQL task, the most straight forward solution.

Comment: Is your enumerator of type 'Foreach ADO Enumerator' ? In that case you should worry about your variable. Your query will return an empty table. That should be handled automatically. Otherwise can you post the error message?

Comment: The package fails at the Execute SQL Task when there is no rows returned from the query with the following error msg: [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "exec usp_Generate_FilesInfo" failed with the following error: "No disconnected record set is available for the specified SQL statement.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Comment: Can you give more info about your SQL select ? 

It looks like that you are not returning an empty table at all.

Comment: The query returns a list of file info if this type of files are NOT already in the table. A simplified version of the query looks like this: IF NOT EXISTS (select * from FileTypeTable where filetype = 'xxx') select 'f1' as fileName, 'p1' as parameter union all select 'f2' as fileName, 'p2' as parameter

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that your query does not return an empty table in case there is nothing to do.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (select * from FileTypeTable where filetype = 'xxx') 
select 'f1' as fileName, 'p1' as parameter 
union all 
select 'f1' as fileName, 'p1' as parameter
```

The easiest solution would be rewriting your query.

```
 select 'f1' as fileName, 'p1' as parameter 
 from fileTableA
 where condition 
 union all 
 select 'f1' as fileName, 'p1' as parameter
 from fileTableB
 where condition
```